# Xamarin iOS - Load Storyboard Reference Programatically

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard-reference

I have 2 storyboards: `Activities.storyboard` and `Contacts.storyboard`.

On `Contacts.storyboard` I have a ViewController: `ContactDetails`.

On `Activities.storyboard` I need refer the `ContactDetails` in `Contacts.storyboard`

I created a `Storyboard Reference` on `Activities.storyboard` and referenced the `ContactDetails`.

[image]

And I tried load this View Controller programmatically

```
var viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(ContactDetails));
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
```

But I didn't work to load programmatically as a normal View Controller

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'ContactDetails'

I know it works this way:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName(nameof(Contact), null);
var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(ContactDetails));
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
```

**But I want to use a Reference View Controller, is it possible?**

Comment: I am fairly certain that it's more common to use the property of a UIViewController named 'Storyboard ID' when trying to instantiate from the applications storyboard, this storyboard ID can also act as a 'restoration identifier'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only way to load Storyboard Reference is with **Segue**.

Programmatically the only way is instantiate the `Storyboard` and after instantiate the `ViewController`

Like this:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName(nameof(Contact), null);
var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(ContactDetails));
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Storyboard ID, it can also be used as a 'restoration identifier' and allows you to instantiate from your storyboard. I would suggest using this approach, it tends to be the simplest way to achieve what you're trying to do.

[image]

It's also worth noting that you have to cast the instantiated UIViewController to it's type (at least I find it makes life easier if I want to pass across variables and such.)

```
ContactDetails viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(ContactDetails)) as ContactDetails;
```

OR

```
ContactDetails viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ContactDetails") as ContactDetails;
```

It's also worth noting that Xamarin iOS 'Storyboard' property of the UIViewController automatically determines the Storyboard reference, and it's worth checking that it is definitely bringing you the pointer to the 'Contact' storyboard (as multiple storyboards are of course possible in iOS development should you choose.)

Comment: I think I don't expressed myself right. I have 2 storyboards, I need refer a ViewController from one to another. Look at my edition please. I tried Cast, but doesn't worked.

Comment: Ok so explain to me what the problem is with using the code that you said worked above. It seems fine to me, you create a reference to the storyboard you want to access and then you instantiate the viewcontroller. I feel as though maybe I'm missing why you can't do that?