# XAMARIN ios pagina di login in C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, storyboard

I'm going to develop a login view on XAMARIN for ios. How i can show a new content view when the user logged in? This content view are linked by a view on storyboard. Thanks you. Im using C#.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYgo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnDkf.png)

Comment: This is an english only site - please rewrite your question in english

Answer (score 0):

You can change the main controller of your app after you login:

```
public void login() {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null);
    var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("myControllerName"); // Your view controller here
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = viewController;
}
```

`MainStoryboard` and `myControllerName` in the above codes are corresponding Storyboard ID you set in the stroyboard and your class name of ViewController.

If you use a `NavigationController`, you can also choose to push to a new controller:

```
public void login() {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null);
    var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("myControllerName"); // Your view controller here
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController,true);
}
```

Refer: [creating-a-storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/?tabs=windows#creating-a-storyboard-with-xcode) and [/xamarin-ios-load-storyboard-reference-programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904487/xamarin-ios-load-storyboard-reference-programatically)

Update:

To set storyBoard ID in properties in Visual-studio

[image]

The `PageTwoVC` in my sample project is the storyboard ID I set in the storyboard.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/ios-storyboard).

Comment: Thanks you, but.. when I run the code it throw a new issue: "Could not find a storyboard name 'name' in Boundle NSBoundle"... why?

Comment: Did you set the "name" as Storyboard ID in storyboard? You can see the second link I shared in my answer, there are pictures there.

Comment: Sorry I omitted an important factor, I'm developing in C # not in swift, I can't find some values ​​and the code rightly doesn't go. Now I have corrected the text.

Comment: I read the handouts but it says how to do it with xacode with xamarin.ios is vague.

Comment: @AlessandroLedda It's the same in visual-studio. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I've update two images of my project, yesterday I must remove your code in loginViewController because I need to run the app. When I try your code Xamarin throw Exception "object not found" refer to <myControllName> (in your code), in mine code Page2 or Page2viewcontroller..

Comment: @AlessandroLedda I uploaded a sample project, check my updated answer please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it. Now everything works, I had been banging my head for over a week but I had not yet understood the management of the storyboards. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlessandroLedda Can you please mark(accept) this answer so that we can help more people with same problem:).